# table view with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uitableview, tap, didselectrowatindexpath

Hi I am developing small IOS application in which I want to display search bar and below it table view. In which I want to hide keyboard when user click outside. For that reason I am using tap recogniser but becoz of that my table view stops listening for row selection.

Here Is my code

```
//inside view did load 
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

but because of this my row selection of table view get disable. that mean `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never get called. Any one have solution for this. Need Help. Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and add the following:

//inside view did load

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

// UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods

```
#pragma mark UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourTableView]) {

        // Don't let selections of auto-complete entries fire the 
        // gesture recognizer
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of code this will solve your problem..

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use TapGestureRecognizer. Use SearchBarDisplayController

[hope this will work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145209/how-to-implement-searchbar-and-search-display-controller-in-tableview-in-xib)

[download a demo project](http://cocoabob.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/SearchDisplayControllerDemo.zip)

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" in the Utilities panel that sounds like it would be perfect for you. [This](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) is a good tutorial that explains how to implement it. This way you won't have the keyboard issue anymore.